# Which software to draw figures?

Tags: windows, images, drawing, vector-graphics

I'm searching a software for windows with which I can easily create figures. I'm currently writing a report in LaTeX. Of course I could do the figures in LaTeX (Tikz) but this is very time consuming.

The figures are for example 3D cube which is divided into smaller cubes (grid) or also simpler figures like a pipeline etc. Important is that the software should allow to draw the figures in an easy way, i.e. point and click (not text based) and no steep learning curve.

Does somebody has some recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the yEd will solve your dilemas. https://www.yworks.com/en/products/yfiles/yed/

If you need to play with details, Inkscape will serve well. (https://inkscape.org/en/about/)

You can also import some more complicated diagram pattern from Inkscape to yEd, or export diagrams from yEd and finish them in Inkscape.